# Is it correct to load the function directly without using autoload?

Tags: php

Problem is autoload  multiple file include not loaded.
Is it correct to load the function directly without using autoload of spl_autoload_register()?

Files:

```
-class(folder)  
--cls.php (file)  
--db.cls.php(file)  
 --config.cls.php(file)  
-index.php(file)  
mp3.cls.php
```

File:cls.php

```
<?php
   class dosya
    {
     static function yukle($a)
     {       $d=__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.str_replace('\\','/',$a).".cls.php";
        if(file_exists($d))
        {
        include_once($d);        
        }
       else{
    return self::yukle($a);

       die($a." sınıfı bulunamadı :(");
       }
     }
    }
?>
```

File:mp3.cls.php

```
<?php
include_once("cls.php");
        dosya::yukle("config");
        dosya::yukle("db");
class mp3 extends db {}
    ?>
```

file:config.cls.php

```
<?php 
include_once("cls.php");
dosya::yukle("db");
    class config extends db {}
    ?>
```

file : db.cls.php

```
<?php include_once("cls.php");
    class db {}
    ?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
  include_once("mp3.cls.php");
$b=new mp3();
?>
```

Comment: the latest version works fine

Comment: Likely your issue is with the naming convention.  Your class is named `dosya` but exists inside `cls.php`  the filename and the class name should match.  Also names like this `mp3.cls.php` fall outside of the PSR standard conventions.  ( with the extra `.` )

Comment: Only problem  undefined variable $dosyal 2.error yukle()  null. Now maybe fixed :/

Comment: For example a class named `\App\Mp3\Dosya` (with namespaces ) should be in a file `App/Mp3/Dosya.php`  ( and not dosya.php case sensitive on Linux ).  when you call `mp3.cls.php` logically how do you resolve that with an autoloader.

Comment: yes I use it as you say  but spl_autload_register()  not loading :/

Comment: Honestly this is a mess, it also looks like you have a infinite loop waiting to happen in your auto-loaders `else` block.  `return self::yukle($a);` this is recursive, without modifying the `$a` variable it will be an infinite loop.

Comment: Change to die($a." Class not found"); else block

Comment: Do you have any other code that needs to be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I will ignore the fact, that you are ignoring the PSR standards for naming conventions and autoloaders.  But one thing I feel compelled to point out is this: ( this is your exact code as it stands but with a sensible format )

```
class dosya
{
    static function yukle($a)
    {       
        $d=__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.str_replace('\\','/',$a).".cls.php";
        if(file_exists($d)){
            include_once($d);        
        }else{
            return self::yukle($a); //this is recursive, and as you dont modify $a, it's infinate

            die($a." sınıfı bulunamadı :("); //this code is never executed.
        }
    }
}
```

If you say try to load a class named `foo`.  Your autoloader will pick that up, turn it into something like this

```
 $b = '/home/public_html/foo.cls.php'
```

This is all fine and dandy, but once your if condition fails because that file does not exist `if(file_exists($d)) = false`.  The else part of your condition runs `return self::yukle($a);`, in which you recusivly call the auto loader function `yukle($a)`.  Now, a key thing here is you are not changing `$a` at all. So it will just repeat the above ( assign $b, fail the file check ) then call itself again, where it repeats again, and again. This will happen infinitely or until your application hits PHP's max_execution_time limit.

I would strongly recommend you avoid doing this.

Cheers!

Comment: I understand. Delete ' return self::yukle($a) ' add die("") method. :) thanks  I researcing and learning Psr standart  ;/

Comment: Here is my auto-loader, part of a bigger framework Im making, it allows you to register multiple "root" namespace path pairs.  https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/Evo/blob/master/Evo/Autoloader.php

Comment: its used like this `AutoLoader::getInstance()->regesterPath( '', __DIR__)`  Which would register no namespace to the current directory. Then you can register other pairs like this `AutoLoader::getInstance()->regesterPath( 'Evo', __DIR__)` which adds the namespace `Evo` to the current directory.  So if I ran `new SomeClass()` it looks for `__DIR__.'/SomeClass.php` and if I do `new \Evo\OtherClass()` it looks for `__DIR__./Evo/OtherClass.php`.  It also handles `new Evo_OtherClass()` correctly as `__DIR__./Evo/OtherClass.php`  In this case I dont have to regester the 2nd path, as it will find it.

Comment: Because it would look for `Evo` as a folder in `__DIR__` regardless, but you could put an entirely different root for it to look in.  PSR says that the `_` underline should be treated as a Directory Seperator, FYI.  Also there are some dependencies on this file ( constants ), so you probably cant use it without changing it some..